# unable to obtain access_token Google+ signin using auth2 javascript

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am trying to integrate google+ login with my website using javascript sdk, Though I am able to validate the user I need to obtain an access token on successful signin which I pass to the server to obtain further information. I went through the documentation in google developer console in this link: [Google Sign-In for Websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference)

in that is could see a method GoogleUser.getAuthResponse() whose response object must contain an access_token.

However in my response object I couldn't find the access_token , but all the remaining key were present. I am not sure if the documentation is outdated.

Please help with me a solution this problem.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth

Comment: it doesnt seem to have a solution

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am having a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686879/google-auth-signin-authresponse-doesnt-have-an-access-token