# Google Sign In get user token

Tags: javascript, google-signin

Try to get the user's token I got:

> Uncaught TypeError: profile.getAuthResponse is not a function

Where

> profile = googleUser

This is my code:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    console.log('Token id: ' + profile.getAuthResponse().id_token);
}
```

Nothing really special there.

I read on google doc that I should use the function *getAuthResponse().id_token* and not *GoogleUser.getId()* for security purposes.

In this question: [Google access_token is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637843/google-access-token-is-undefined)
Here Sharkos suggest to use *gapi.auth.getToken().access_token* but I **got null**

Any ideas why I got that error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google access\_token is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637843/google-access-token-is-undefined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
    console.log('Token id: ' + googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
}
```

You set var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile(); Therefore, you can't use getAuthResponse() on getBasicProfile(). it has to be googleUser.getAuthResponse()

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#googleusergetauthresponseincludeauthorizationdata